# Automate Outlook first time opening

Tags: powershell, scripting, outlook

I wanted to configure a script that would basically take the opening Outlook 2010 for the first time dialog and accept the defaults. We have an exchange server that is currently running that populates the first time fields with the user's AD information. Basically I wanted to write a script in powershell that would accept the default values that AD has filled in and complete the install. Once the install is complete Outlook will set up a copy of the user's mailbox and all of their mail will be pulled down to the computer.

I have been trying and trying in powershell to accomplish the acceptance of defaults to no avail. Is there any possible way to link a powershell script with outlook and have it accept GUI dialogs?

I have not written any code to do this other than a little initialization script in powershell. I am also a powershell newbie so I know enough to create a com object and call that object so that it can open Outlook but that is as far as I can go.

Can someone please give me some help? Here is what I have but it really doesn't work that well:

```
$mail = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$namespace = $mail.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder("olFolderInbox")
$explorer = $folder.GetExplorer()
$explorer.Display()
```

Comment: which version of outlook? please post the script which you use to run the outlook executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the WASP snap-in at http://wasp.codeplex.com/. It allows UI automation by finding widows and sending commands to those windows. It is easy to use and makes tasks like mine a lot easier. It is only a 32 bit .dll but it works for Powershell >= 2.0. Thank you all for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how far you've gotten with PowerShell, but review [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx).

Consider other Windows GUI scripting engines, they should solve this problem pretty easily - more easily than PowerShell scripting.

Try:

- [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)
- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: I'll look into it. I wanted a solution in powershell just because a bigger part of my library is being written in it and I know that it will be on most machines.

Comment: It was a very interesting read and helped me understand a lot about control for UI elements but not quite what I was looking for. Thank you!